# Not been able to use Shift + 6 on Wine

Tags: wine, games, keyboard-layout

I've been having a problem running a game through wine (starcraft 2), when i need to add units to an existing control group i press shift + 6 in game,this doesn't seems to have any output at all, i've tried to check with the ingame chat, but the normal output should be "^" but there's nothing.
I'm using the English, int with dead keys as my layout.

Comment: Is the caret symbol used for circumflexes with that keyboard layout?

Comment: Yes it is, seems the " and ' also don't work while in game.

Answer (score 0):

To get a caret symbol with dead keys, press space after the caret.

"Dead keys" means that some keys don't work normally. Instead, they're used to modify other characters. For example, <kbd>^</kbd> followed by <kbd>O</kbd> produces `ô`.

You may wish to use another layout like `English (US, alternative international)` (which I believe uses <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> followed by <kbd>O</kbd> for `ô`) if you need international characters or `English (US)` if you don't.